# How long should it take until a new Universal Analytics property starts collecting data?

Tags: google-analytics, tracking, universal-analytics

I set up a new Universal Analytics property about 1 hour ago and added the code to my page. Everything looks fine and the same code is working well on other pages.

However, I cannot see any real-time data in the reports. If I only change the property ID in my code an leave everything else the same real-time data immediately shows up.

Does it take some time and if so how much until a property starts collecting data?

Answer (score 0):

Well then ... it just started reporting data. Hope this post at least helps some others while being too impatient.

Took about 60 Minutes until it started to collect data.

Answer (score 0):

If you have correctly installed the tracking snippet, collection will start immediately and you can verify in real time reports, assuming you are not filtering your own visits. Data won't appear in standard reports, however, for up to 24 hours (and you could even get data in as short as 1 hour as you have observed).